# A column in my DB is in format "k000". How do I copy part of this string and update column in same table inputting those three char?

Tags: mysql, sql

One of the table entries in my database is in the format "k000" and I want to copy part of this string (first 3 pos) and update another column in the same table inputting those three characters. How can I do it using PHPMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine 2 queries, a SELECT LEFT(col_name, 3) to get the 3 firsts character of a string and an UPDATE one.

Using the SQL tab in PHPMyAdmin, try this kind of query :

```
UPDATE table_name
    SET col_name = (SELECT LEFT(col_name , 3)
                        FROM table_name
                        WHERE where_clause)
    WHERE where_clause
```

Comment: it helped. thatnks a lot